# Duplicate class org.openqa.selenium Error on Anroid Studio

Tags: selenium, android-studio, dependencies, appium

[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXbHF.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w44yo.png)

first time setting android studio using appium and selenium for testing mobile apps